# How to manipulate column entries using only one specific output of a function that returns several values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply

I have a dataframe like this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': range(4), 'b': range(2, 6)})

   a  b
0  0  2
1  1  3
2  2  4
3  3  5
```

and I have a function that returns several values. Here I just use a **dummy function** that returns the minimum and maximum for a certain input iterable:

```
def return_min_max(x):
    return (np.min(x), np.max(x))
```

Now I want to e.g. add the maximum of each column to each value in the respective column.

So

```
df.apply(return_min_max)
```

gives

```
a    (0, 3)
b    (2, 5)
```

and then

```
df.add(df.apply(return_min_max).apply(lambda x: x[1]))
```

yields the desired outcome

```
   a   b
0  3   7
1  4   8
2  5   9
3  6  10
```

I am wondering whether there is a more straightforward way that avoids the two chained `apply`'s.

Just to make sure:

I am NOT interested in a

```
df.add(df.max())
```

type solution. I highlighted the `dummy_function` to illustrate that this not my actual function but just serves as a minimal example function that has several outputs.

Comment: Your first problem is the dummy `return_min_max` function. As you mentioned, you don't want `apply`, but without more detail, it's nearly impossible to tell how to vectorize that function. The second part is easy with numpy broadcast`.

Comment: What's the reason you want to write functions that return multiple values if I may ask?

Comment: @QuangHoang: The function is fixed and I cannot change it, so vectorizing it won't work. How would you use numpy broadcasting here?

Comment: @Erfan: Not my function, but I have to take what I get ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DataFrame.max` will returns a Series of the column-wise maximum values. `DataFrame.add()` will then add this `Series`, aligning on columns.

```
df.add(df.max())

#   a   b
#0  3   7
#1  4   8
#2  5   9
#3  6  10
```

---

If you're real function is much more complicated, there are a few alternatives.

Keep it as is, use `.str` to access the max element.

```
def return_min_max(x):
    return (np.min(x), np.max(x))

df.add(df.apply(return_min_max).str[1])
```

Consider returning a Series with the index being descriptive about what is returned:

```
def return_min_max(x):
    return pd.Series([np.min(x), np.max(x)], index=['min', 'max'])

df.add(df.apply(return_min_max).loc['max'])
```

Or if the returns can be separated (in this case `max` and `min` really don't need to be done in the same function), it's simpler to have them separated:

```
def return_max(x):
    return np.max(x)

df.add(df.apply(return_max))
```

Comment: The `.str[1]` solution looks good. Thanks! The other solutions won't work, as the function is indeed far more complicated.

Answer (score 3):

At a second look, your `return_min_max` is a column function. So it is not that bad. You can do, e.g:

```
# create a dataframe for easy access
ret_df = pd.DataFrame(df.apply(return_min_max).to_dict())
#    a  b
# 0  0  2
# 1  3  5

# add 
df.add(ret_df.loc[1], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
   a   b
0  3   7
1  4   8
2  5   9
3  6  10
```

And numpy broadcast:

```
df.values[None,:] + ret_df.values[:,None]
```

gives:

```
array([[[ 0,  4],
        [ 1,  5],
        [ 2,  6],
        [ 3,  7]],

       [[ 3,  7],
        [ 4,  8],
        [ 5,  9],
        [ 6, 10]]], dtype=int64)
```